# Observables not returning the data

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing an Angular 2 app which makes web api calls. I am currently using visual studio 2015 ,MVC5 webapi, typescript and  Observables to make the web api calls from client script. It looks like there is some issue with the web api call. I can see that the webapi is being called but result probably is not returned in time when it is needed. Please see the error message and my code below

**Error message**

[image]
**Web Api method**

```
[Route("api/customerorder")]
    public class CustomerOrderController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<CustomerViewModel> GetCustomerOrder()
        {
            return new List<CustomerViewModel>
            {
                new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Jammy", LastName = "Oliver" , City = "London" , OrderCount = 12 },
                new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Sam", LastName = "Walter" , City = "Birmingham" , OrderCount = 12 },
                new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = "Shanks" , City = "Liverpool" , OrderCount = 12 },
                new CustomerViewModel { FirstName = "Dan", LastName = "Barack" , City = "Kent" , OrderCount = 12 },
                new CustomerViewModel {  FirstName = "Mike", LastName = "Jagger" , City = "Norwich" , OrderCount = 12 }
            };
        }
    }
```

**Customer.Service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService
{

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    private  customerOrderUrl = 'http://localhost:62440/api/customerorder';

    getCustomerOrders(): Observable<CustomerOrder[]> {

        return this.http.get(this.customerOrderUrl)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server Error'));
    }
}
```

So if you see the code below, I am trying to call webapi via the loadCustomerOrder method which in turn invokes the service call in Customer.Service.ts.

**Customer.Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input,OnChanges} from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerOrder } from './customerOrder';
import { CustomerService } from './customer.service';
import { GridModule, GridDataResult, PageChangeEvent, SortDescriptor, orderBy } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'cust',
    templateUrl: '/app/customers/customer.component.html',
    providers: [CustomerService]
})

export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {

    private gridView: GridDataResult;
    private sort: SortDescriptor[] = [];
    private data: any[];

    private pageSize: number = 10;
    private skip: number = 0;
    title = 'Customer List';
    customerorder: CustomerOrder[];


    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.title = 'Customers';

    }

    constructor(private _custService: CustomerService)
    {
        this.data = [];
        this.loadCustomerOrder();
    }


    loadCustomerOrder(): void {

        this._custService.getCustomerOrders()
            .subscribe(
            CustomerOrder => this.customerorder = CustomerOrder,

            err => console.log(err)

            );
        this.data = this.customerorder;
        this.loadData();
        }

    private loadData(): void {
        this.gridView = {
            data: this.handleData(),
            total: this.data.length
        };
    }

    private handleData() {
        var pagedData = this.data.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize)
        if (!this.sort) { return pagedData; }

        var orderedAndPagedData = orderBy(pagedData, this.sort);
        return orderedAndPagedData;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
   loadCustomerOrder(): void {

        this._custService.getCustomerOrders()
            .subscribe(
            CustomerOrder => this.customerorder = CustomerOrder,

            err => console.log(err)

            );
        this.data = this.customerorder;
        this.loadData();
        }
```

to

```
   loadCustomerOrder(): void {

        this._custService.getCustomerOrders()
            .subscribe(
            (CustomerOrder) => {
                this.customerorder = CustomerOrder

                this.data = this.customerorder;
                this.loadData();

            },

            err => console.log(err)

            );
        }
```

since `getCustomerOrders` is an async function your `this.customerorder` is `undefined` when you assign it to `this.data`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `loadCustomerOrder` function to as below and call `this.loadCustomerOrder();` inside `ngOnInit` instead of `constructor` as `ngOnInit` is more preferred over `constructor` :

```
loadCustomerOrder(): void {
  this._custService.getCustomerOrders().subscribe(
    customerOrder =>  {
      this.customerorder = customerOrder;
      this.data = customerOrder;
    }, err => console.log(err)
  );      
  this.loadData();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks the error certainly has gone but when I print the following in the html, only data property prints the values and not the gridview property. In my logic I am assigning it to the gridview property too, to perform paging related functionality. 
<div>{{gridView | json}}</div>
<div>{{data | json}}</div>